# Executing a SQL statement inside a stored procedure, how to store the result of that SQL statement into a variable for later use?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, stored-procedures

i need to execute several SQL statements inside an stored procedure, save the result into a variable for later use.

```
  SET NOCOUNT OFF
  DECLARE @P TABLE
  @P  = SELECT d.Periodo 
  from [SISACT].DEPRECIACIONES d, [SISACT].CONTROL_PERIODO c 
  where c.vigente = 1 AND d.Periodo = c.periodo

  IF @@ROWCOUNT > 0
     PRINT 'Periodo ya depreciado'
```

So later i can do something like this

```
UPDATE [SISACT].ACTIVOS_FIJOS set ultimo_periodo = @p.periodo ...
```

I know the `@P = SELECT is wrong`, i saw an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9377775/store-the-result-of-a-stored-procedure-without-using-an-output-parameter) where they used another stored procedure instead of a SELECT statement, i want to know if this is possible without using a stored procedure. If so, how? I'm just going to use the query once in only one stored procedure so i see no point into putting it in another stored procedure. I'm new to T-SQL and SQL server  , i'm learning on my own as well and i'm sorry if this is an stupid question.

P.S: The query in this case should return just one record. I'm using SQL SERVER 2008 Express.

Thank you for any help in advance.

Comment: Why are u using table variable, is d.Periodo integer? Table variables usually used when you want to store more then one row...

Comment: No, periodo is CHAR(6), i was following the example i posted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that what you want.

```
  SET NOCOUNT OFF
  DECLARE @P as CHAR(6)
  SELECT p@ = d.Periodo from [SISACT].DEPRECIACIONES d, [SISACT].CONTROL_PERIODO c where c.vigente = 1 AND d.Periodo = c.periodo
  IF @@ROWCOUNT > 0
     PRINT 'Periodo ya depreciado'
```

and later you can use

```
UPDATE [SISACT].ACTIVOS_FIJOS set ultimo_periodo = @p
```